# What can I do with a hex String literal?

Tags: java, hex

I'm learning Java, and I'm on a book chapter about hex String literals.  It tells me that I can create a hex String literal in this format: "\uxxxx".  So I tried this:

```
char c = '\u0010';
int x = c;
System.out.println(x);  // prints 16.
```

Firstly, why does the following hex String literal cause a compilation error?  I was expecting that 'a' in hex would equal 10 in decimal.

```
char c = '\u000a';
```

Returns the following error:

```
..\src\pkgs\main\Main.java:360: error: illegal line end in character literal
                char c = '\u000a';
```

Secondly, because of my novice Java status, I'm currently not able to appreciate what hex String literals are used for.  Why would I want to use one?  Can someone please provide me with a "real world" example of their use?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm, strange, since `'\u000b'` does work... You have hit a peculiar character the first time you tried it :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted already, Unicode escapes are actually [processed during compilation as a replacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4):

> Because Unicode escapes are processed very early, it is not correct to write '\u000a' for a character literal whose value is linefeed (LF); the Unicode escape \u000a is transformed into an actual linefeed in translation step 1 (§3.3) and the linefeed becomes a LineTerminator in step 2 (§3.4), and so the character literal is not valid in step 3. Instead, one should use the escape sequence '\n' (§3.10.6). Similarly, it is not correct to write '\u000d' for a character literal whose value is carriage return (CR). Instead, use '\r'.

This aspect of Unicode escapes is not just limited to character literals. For example, the following will print "hello world":

```
// \u000A System.out.println("hello world");
```

Another way to get special characters beyond an escape is to use an integer literal:

```
static final char NUL = 0x0000;
```

As for their usefulness, for one, because otherwise you'd have to copy and paste special characters or type them in with some keyboard combination. The other reason is that certain characters don't have a proper visual representation. Examples of this are null, escape, backspace and delete. Also code point 7, the bell character, which is actually an instruction for the computer to emit a beep when it gets printed.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that the compiler gives an error is because the compiler will parse the `\u000a` to `CR`

```
char A = '\u000A';
```

therefore becomes...

```
char A ='
';
```

which results in a compile-time error. To avoid this error, always use the special escape characters `'\n'` (line feed) and `'\r'` (carriage return).

Comment: Quotes do dissapear? Isn't it `char A='<CR>'`; (with CR being zero-with whitespace that breaks the line?)

Comment: I believe your "therefore becomes" should be `char A = '(new line)';`. Note that `char A =;` gives a different error.

Comment: Uh, good to know... (what is the equivalent for `\r` by the way?)

Comment: quetzalcoatl and Dukeling are right. If it didn't, the compiler error wouldn't be "illegal line end in character literal". (I've taken the liberty of editing it for you.)

Comment: @fge: `\n` is character 10 (0x0a). `\r` is character 13 (0x0d).

Answer (score 0):

Char in Java is of 2 bytes and hence you can print Unicode characters using char.
So if you know unicode character code, then you can store it as hex literal in char and you can use the other language characters.

You can visit this link:
http://voices.yahoo.com/how-print-unicode-characters-java-12507717.html

For understanding the use of hex literals

Comment: Why was this answer down voted?  In my o.p., I was hoping that someone would answer the "Secondly..." part.  Unfortunately, I don't fully understand this answer.  Can someone please elaborate/expand on what @Mo.Ashfaq is saying?  Thanks.

Comment: @user2911290 Likely it was down-voted because the first sentence is wrong. You *cannot* represent all Unicode characters using a `char`. The sixteen bits (a pair of octets) backing the `char` has a range of about 65,000. But Unicode defines over 110,000 characters numbered across a range of over a million. So `char` cannot possibly represent all Unicode characters.